# No direcciona bien cuando valido en Codeigniter

Tags: php, validación, codeigniter-3

Mi problema es el siguiente: Estoy tratando de hacer un formulario pero no puedo direccionar bien cuando intento corregir la validacion despues de a respuesta de que los datos no son validos mediante el condicional if. La idea es que debo llenar los datos del formulario luego me lleva a la vista nuevamente para completar y corregir los errores pero al volver a darle submit me da error como si volviera a repetir la funcion o algo asi y no envia. A continuacion el codigo y las pantallas del procedimiento.

Controlador

```
class Emails extends CI_Controller{
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->library(array('email', 'form_validation'));
    }

$this->load->library(array('email', 'form_validation'));} function index(){
$datos['contenido'] = 'emails';
$this->load->view('contacto/mailcontacto', $datos); } function enviar() {

$nombre = $this->input->post('nombre');
$telefono = $this->input->post('telefono');
$email = $this->input->post('email');
$asunto = $this->input->post('asunto');
$mensaje = $this->input->post('mensaje');
$body_msg =  '<html><body><br />'. '<h2><font face="times new roman" color="#da0021"><span><font face="times  new roman" color="#00769f"> CONTACTO </h2></font>'.'<table rules="all" style="border-width: 1px; border-style: dashed; border-  color: #50a9d5; " cellpadding="10">' ."<tr><td><strong>Nombre</strong> </td><td>" . $nombre . "</td></tr>"."<tr><td><strong>Telefono:</strong> </td><td>" . $telefono . "</td></tr>"."<tr style=style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>Enviado desde:</strong>   </td><td>" . $email. "</td></tr>"."<tr><td><strong>Asunto:</strong> </td><td>" . $asunto . "</td></tr>"."<tr><td><strong>Mensaje:</strong> </td><td>" . $mensaje . "</td></tr>"."<br />"; //Validaciones //Nombre del campo, titulo, restricciones
$this->form_validation->set_rules('nombre', 'Nombre','required|min_length[3]|alpha|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|min_length[3]|valid_email|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('telefono', 'Telefono', 'required|numeric');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('asunto', 'Asunto', 'required|min_length[3]|alpha|trim');
$this->form_validation->set_rules('mensaje', 'Mensaje', 'required|min_length[3]|alpha|trim'); if( $this->form_validation->run() === FALSE){
$datos['contenido'] = 'emails';
$this->load->view('contacto', $datos);  } else{ //Acción a tomas si no existe ningun error // Datos para enviar el correo
$this->email->from('desde@gmail.com', 'Contacto');
$this->email->to('para@gmail.com');
$this->email->subject($asunto);               
$this->email->message($body_msg );
$this->email->attach('img/logo.png');
$this->email->send(); redirect('contacto'); // Se direcciona } }} ?>`
```

**application/config/config.php**

```
$config['base_url'] = 'http://www.dominio.com/';
```

**application/config/autoload.php**

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation', 'session');
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form')
```

**application/config/routes.php**

```
$route['default_controller'] = "inicio";  // Cambiado el default por inicio
$route['404_override']  = '';
$route['enviar'] = 'emails/enviar';
```

**application/views/mailcontacto.php**

```
<form action="emails/enviar" method="post">
<table style="margin:-01px auto; width:100%;background:#ffffff"> <tr>
      <td style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px"><label><a style="color:#E41519">&nbsp;</a><a style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; ">Envianos un mensaje o requerimiento y un asesor lo contactara a la brevedad posible:
      </a></label></td>

    </tr></tbody></table>

    <table style="width:100%; background:#ffffff;">
  <tbody>
   <tr>

       <td style=" background:#05C421"><?php if(isset($mensaje)) echo $mensaje; ?></h2>
        <?=validation_errors();?><!--mostrar los errores de validación--></td></tr>
  </tbody>

</table>
<table style="width:100%; height:auto; background:#ffffff; margin:05px auto;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><table style="margin:-50px auto; width:100%;  width:60%; background:#ffffff">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:20px 10px 10px 10px"><table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><label><a style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; ">Nombre:
      </a></label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="padding:20px 10px 10px 10px"><table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><label><a style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; ">Tel&eacute;fono:
      </a></label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input  type="text"  placeholder=" id="nombre" name="nombre" class="form-control logpadding margtop10 mayuscula" required  title="Se necesita un nombre minimo dos letras"  autofocus="autofocus" value="<?php echo set_value('nombre') ?>" /></td>

      <td>&nbsp;</td>
     <td><input type="text" placeholder="0261000000" id="telefono" name="telefono" class="form-control logpadding margtop10" required pattern="^\+?\d{1,3}?[- .]?\(?(?:\d{2,3})\)?[- .]?\d\d\d[- .]?\d\d\d\d$" title="Se necesita un minimo 10 numeros incluyendo codigo de area sin espacios"  autofocus="autofocus" value="<?php echo set_value('telefono') ?>"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <tr><td ><a style="color:#F0080C"><?php  echo form_error('nombre')  ?></a>  </td><td></td><td><a style="color:#F0080C"><?php  echo form_error('telefono')  ?></a> </td></tr>
      <td><a style="color:#24BCFC"> Solo  Formato Letras permitidas</a></td><br/><br/>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td><a style="color:#24BCFC">Solo  Formato N&uacute;meros permitidos</a></td><br/><br/>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px"><table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><br/>
      <label><a style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; ">Pais:
      </a></label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
</td
      ><td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px"><table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><br/>
      <label><a style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; ">Ciudad:
      </a></label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><tr><td><a style="color:#F0080C"><?php  echo form_error('pais') ?></a></td><td></td><td><a style="color:#F0080C"><?php  echo form_error('ciudad') ?></a></td></tr>
      <td><input type="text"  id="pais" name="pais" class="form-control logpadding margtop10" value="<?php echo set_value('pais') ?>"/></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input type="text"  id="ciudad" name="ciudad" class="form-control logpadding margtop10" value="<?php echo set_value('ciudad') ?>"/></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px"><table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><br/><label><a style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; ">Email:
      </a></label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
       <td style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px"><table width="200" border="1">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
       <td><br/>
       <label><a style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; ">Asunto:
      </a></label></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><tr><td><a style="color:#F0080C"><?php  echo form_error('email') ?></a></td><td></td><td><a style="color:#F0080C"><?php  echo form_error('asunto') ?></a></td></tr>
      <td><input type="text" placeholder="" id="email" name="email" class="form-control logpadding margtop10" required pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*@[a-zA-Z0-9_]+([.][a-zA-Z0-9_]+)*[.][a-zA-Z]{1,5}"  title="Se necesita un formato de email tunombre@dominio.com"  autofocus="autofocus" value="<?php echo set_value('email') ?>" /></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input  type="text"  placeholder="" id="asunto" name="asunto" class="form-control logpadding margtop10 mayuscula" required  title="Se necesita un nombre minimo dos letras"  autofocus="autofocus" value="<?php echo set_value('asunto') ?>" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td> <a style="color:#24BCFC"> Solo Formato Email permitido</a>
        <br/><br/></td>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td> <a style="color:#E41519"> </a>
        <br/><br/></td>
    </tr>

</table></td></tr><tr><td><table style="margin:50px auto; width:100%;  width:60%; background:#ffffff"> <tr>
      <td style="padding:10px 10px 10px 10px">  <label><a style="font-family: 'Roadgeek 2005 Series 1B', sans-serif; font-size:16px; color:#000000; ">¿En que podemos ayudarte?:
      </a></label></td>

    </tr><tr><td><textarea class="mayuscula"  rows="04" id="mensaje" name="mensaje"  style="margin-top:08px; width:80%"  required pattern="[a-zA-Z]+{2,50}" title="Se necesita un mensaje o requerimiento minimo dos letras"  autofocus="autofocus" value="<?php echo set_value('mensaje, $foo') ?>"/></textarea></td></tr><tr><td><a style="color:#F0080C"><?php  echo form_error('mensaje') ?></a></td></tr></table></td></tr></tbody></table>
<table style="width:100%; background:#ffffff;">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><button  style=" margin:0 auto; type="submit" value="enviar" class="btn btn-primary">Enviar</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>

</table>

</form>
```

Pantalla 2 Devolviendo los errores y corrigiendo el formulario

[image: Pantalla 2 Devolviendo los errores y corrigiendo el formulario]

Aqui el error Pantalla 3 ERROR

[image: Pantalla 3 ERROR]

Comment: Hola @Alejandro. Por favor **no publiques las preguntas nuevamente**. Tampoco crees múltiples cuentas para recibir más atención, no es saludable para el sitio ni para la comunidad. Asimismo, si tienes más problemas luego de aplicar una solución en una pregunta, por favor continúa en esa misma pregunta. Si los problemas son sobre algo externo al problema que tenías anteriorment, entonces allí sí se necesita publicar una nueva pregunta.

Comment: Ok entendido Luiggi Gracias !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error se da por que en el form, el action esta dirigido a la ruta relativa desde donde te encuentras en ese momento, es decir:

```
<form action="emails/enviar" method="post">
```

Si te encuentras en: `www.tusitio.com/emails/enviar/` y envías otra petición al mismo sitio esta petición asumirá que desde el url actual vas de nuevo a `email/enviar` y te generará un url como: `www.tusitio.com/emails/enviar/emails/enviar`

Para solucionarlo puedes colocar el action de la siguiente manera:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url();?>/emails/enviar" method="post">
```

De manera que envías toda la dirección donde se encuentra tu controlador.

Comment: Excelente Gracias Juan!!!! Solucionado.